# How to remove a specific object in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example I have a list that looks like this:

```
l = [(1,2),(1,3),(4,1)]
```

how can I remove item (1,3) without knowing the index of the item?

I tried `l.pop((1,3))` but I got this error message: `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: You want `l.remove((1,3))`

Comment: With `.remove(..)`

Comment: @CJ59 This worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [(1,2),(1,3),(4,1)]
print(l) #[(1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 1)]
l.remove((1,3))
print(l) #[(1, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked